# How do I get current time in milliseconds in Loadrunner?

Tags: time, epoch, loadrunner

I am looking for the equivalent of Java's System.currentTimeMillis() in Loadrunner. I could only find lr_save_datetime("%x%X", 0, "now"); which outputs in date and time format but not the time since epoch.

In C, time.h can provide this but #include "time.h" in the LR script resulted in compilation errors. time.h probably has dependencies on other .h and .inl files.

I got #error ERROR: Only Win32 target supported! even though I had copied all the files it complained were missing, from the Visual studio C++ compilers folder. (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\time.h)

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use **lr_save_timestamp** to get the timestamp in seconds – it is more powerful than web_save_timestamp_param.

My documentation for the function:

```
int lr_save_timestamp( const char* tmstampParam, [DIGITS,] LAST );
```

**tmstampParam**

The name of the parameter to store the timestamp.

**DIGITS**

Optional. The number of digits for the timestamp (integer). The default is 13 (epoch time including 3 digits of millisecond precision).

If the value of DIGITS is less than 1 or more than 16, the default is used

In this example, the timestamp is saved and a length of 10 digits is specified. Returns the epoch time in seconds

```
lr_save_timestamp(“param”, “DIGITS=10″, LAST );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can output the number of seconds since 01/01/1970 like the UNIX-style format by using the 'time()' function:

```
long t;  // create the variable

// output the seconds to the log
lr_output_message("seconds since 01/01/1970 : %d", 
                   time(t) ); // populate the variable
                              // with the current seconds count 
------------------------------------------------------------------
Output: Action.c(11): time : 1362080852
```

If you're looking for the current millisecond you can get that within LoadRunner by creating a new 'Date/Time' parameter in the Parameters list and using the format code '%S.000'. Once this is in place call it like this:

`lr_eval_string("{datetime_param_name}");`

As an example, if you enter this in the Date/Time parameter format field:
%H%M%S.000

... for current hour, minute, seconds and miliseconds you get...
133808.132

For some reason the format code '%S.000' works in the Date/Time parameter list but not for lr_save_datetime() function. If you used the same code on the function you would get this:
133808.000

Answer (score 0):

web_save_timestamp_param(); returns 13 digit millisecond precision time since epoch.

LoadRunner doesn't use Visual C/C++ for the C run time engine.  It uses LCC, the lightweight cross platform C compiler.   So, if you need to extend with additional libraries I recommend the ones which come with LCC.    For more information on LCC please refer to 
[The University of Virgina Department of Computer Science website on LCC for Windows](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~lcc-win32/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ftime utility function. It accepts pointer to the *timeb* struct and fills its with current time value.

*timeb* structure is defined as follows:

```
struct timeb {
   time_t time; //seconds since epoch
   unsigned short millis; //milliseconds since time field
   short timezone;
   short daytimesaveflag;
}
```

according to LR Function reference to use ftime function you need to define timeb structure (**do not include time.h**)

```
  struct timeb {
   long time; //seconds since epoch
   unsigned short millis; //milliseconds since time field
   short timezone;
   short daytimesaveflag;
} timestruct;
long millisSinceEpoch=0 
ftime(&timestruct);
millisSinceEpoch=timestruct.time_t*1000+timestruct.millis;
```

Answer (score -1):

under parameterisation choose date and time parameter type, there we have so many formats.check it once....i hope it will solve your problem with out any coding effort